# How to get only desirable comparisons from post-hoc

Tags: r, anova, post-hoc

I have some experimental data that I'm trying to analyze.
I have 1 response variable and 3 explanatory variables (these are factor variables).
The explanatory variables are the presence of a disease(positive and negative),
a genetic profile (X and Y), and whether or not an MRI contrast agent was given
(YES and NO).

Structure of data looks like this:

```
     measurement   profile  disease contrast
1    -1.76269      X        NEG       YES
2    -0.34492      X        NEG       NO
3     0.57455      X        POS       YES
4     2.16539      X        POS       NO
            .      .          .        .
            .      .          .        .
            .      .          .        .
77   -1.76269      Y        NEG       YES
78   -0.34492      Y        NEG       NO
79    0.57455      Y        POS       YES
80    2.16539      Y        POS       NO
```

I looked into using ANOVA for this analysis but the post hoc **Tukey HSD
looks at all possible combinations** of the explanatory variables so **it
makes far more comparisons than I actually care about.**

We have some specific hypotheses that, e.g.:
X.NEG.NO will differ from Y.NEG.NO,
X.NEG.NO will differ form X.NEG.YES,
X.NEG.NO will differ from X.POS.NO, etc.

***(notice that each compared group "consist" from interaction of all three variables)***

How to get only some specific comparisons from TukeyHSD?
Is appropriate to make 
Is there a better approach?

```
Reproducible example:

my.data <- data.frame(measurement = rnorm(80),
                      my.profile = rep(c("X","Y"), each = 40),
                      my.disease = rep(c("NEG","NEG","POS","POS"), times=20),
                      my.contrast = rep(c("NO","YES"), times = 40))
```

Comment: I don't have much background in DOE, but I'll try to answer the best I can.  I don't think this could be considered an orthogonal design.  The full set of comparisons I need to make is: X.NEG.NO vs. Y.NEG.NO, X.POS.NO vs Y.POS.NO; X.NEG.NO vs X.NEG.YES Y.NEG.NO vs Y.NEG.YES; X.POS.NO vs X.POS.YES, Y.POS.NO vs Y.POS.YES; X.NEG.NO vs X.POS.NO, Y.NEG.NO vs Y.POS.NO; X.NEG.YES vs X.POS.YES, Y.NEG.YES vs Y.POS.YES

Comment: All other comparisons are meaningless.I also have 3 different regions that I want to consider all these comparisons in, but they are separate so it doesn't make sense to compare across them.

Comment: For some comparisons they do but for others they don't (e.g. n=11 vs n=9).

Comment: Thanks!  Do I perform diagnostics with the summary command?  Also, is there a name for this process so that I can cite it when I write up my results?  And when you say I can only compare based on profile and contrast, that means I should perform a bivariate test ignoring the disease factor? (e.g. `t.test(data$measurement[data$profile=="X"], data$measurement[data$profile == "Y"]`

Comment: No, please edit away if you think it makes it clearer.

Comment: There is an additional complication.  I've posted data from one region, but I have 2 other regions.  This is imaging data and one of the regions is a phantom (basically a tube of water) put in with the patient in order to rule out that significant observations are not due to artifacts in the image.  So do you think I should repeat this same process on the phantom data? I will have to think about sending the data set.

Comment: I think maybe I didn't use the right language in my original post.  If I have only planned comparisons (i.e. I'm not dating mining for significant p-values), can I just carry out my pairwise statistical tests and skip the ANOVA entirely?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Suppose that we have one response variable and one explanatory variable (5 levels).

```
con.data <- data.frame(x = c(rnorm(75), c(rnorm(75)+5)),
                      category = rep(c("A","B1","B2","C1","C2"), each=30))
```

If we do **ANOVA** followed by classical **TukeyHSD post-hoc**...

```
m1 <- aov(con.data$x ~ con.data$category); summary(m1)
TukeyHSD(m1)

           diff        lwr      upr     p adj
B1-A  0.1877877 -0.9109837 1.286559 0.9897357
B2-A  2.2050543  1.1062829 3.303826 0.0000013
C1-A  4.5951737  3.4964022 5.693945 0.0000000
C2-A  4.7790488  3.6802773 5.877820 0.0000000
B2-B1 2.0172666  0.9184952 3.116038 0.0000117
C1-B1 4.4073860  3.3086145 5.506157 0.0000000
C2-B1 4.5912611  3.4924896 5.690033 0.0000000
C1-B2 2.3901193  1.2913479 3.488891 0.0000001
C2-B2 2.5739944  1.4752230 3.672766 0.0000000
C2-C1 0.1838751 -0.9148963 1.282647 0.9905238
```

...we obtain **all possible combinations**.

If you want to make only **comparison that are interesting to you**, use **CONTRASTS**.

In R there are several default contrast matrices ([overview](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/65059_586f394d8eb84f84b1baaf56ffb6b47f.html)):

**treatment, helmert, sum , polynomial**... but you can *create* your own.

First - **decide which comparisons you are interested in**.

Then create a contrast matrix:

```
contrasts(con.data$category) <- cbind(c(1,-1/4,-1/4,-1/4,-1/4),
                                     c(0,-1/2,-1/2,1/2,1/2),
                                     c(0,0,0,1/2,-1/2),
                                     c(0,-1/2,1/2,0,0))
```

look at this table for reference:

```
contrasts(con.data$category)
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
A   1.00  0.0  0.0  0.0
B1 -0.25 -0.5  0.0 -0.5
B2 -0.25 -0.5  0.0  0.5
C1 -0.25  0.5  0.5  0.0
C2 -0.25  0.5 -0.5  0.0
```

Take notice that sum of **each column is equal to 0**.

If you have 5 levels in a factor, there can be only 4 comparisons,
due to degrees of freedom.

*In the **first** column you compare mean of "A" with mean of all others categories.*

*In the **second** column you compare only category "B" with "C" (B1+B2 vs. C1+C2)*.

*In the **third** column you compare only within "C" category (C1 vs. C2)*.

*In the **fourth** column you compare only within "B" category (B1 vs. B2)*.

---

To see the results **re-make the ANOVA** with created contrast matrix.

```
summary(lm(con.data$x, con.data$category)) 


  Coefficients:
                    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
  (Intercept)         2.5910     0.1258  20.599  < 2e-16 ***
  con.data$category1  -2.3534     0.2516  -9.355  < 2e-16 ***
  con.data$category2   3.4907     0.2813  12.411  < 2e-16 ***
  con.data$category3  -0.1839     0.3978  -0.462    0.645    
  con.data$category4   2.0173     0.3978   5.072 1.19e-06 ***
```

...and each **row** in the table **corresponds to each comparison (column in contrast matrix) made**.
(i.e.  con.data$category1 is significant so there is significant difference between
mean of "A" vs. mean of all others groups...etc.)

In short:

**Try to make a contrast matrix containing only comparisons you are interested in. With the example above it should not be difficult.**

---

**However !!!**

I would not use post-hoc (or contrasts) on data immediately. It is
like to teach a model to "run" before it can "walk". So as a first thing
I would **create a model containing all variables**. Subsequently, remove all
non-significant variables (or their interaction) according to **marginality
rule**. **This procedure (reduction) will determine if all your desired comparisons are necessary.**

So try to make **full model**:

```
m1 <- glm(measurement ~ my.profile*my.contrast*my.disease, data = my.data)
anova(m1, test = "F")
```

For example, if factor "disease" will not be significant (alone or in interaction - it should not be included in post-hoc.

Suppose the results of **m1** model will look like this:

```
my.profile                        0.00012 **
my.contrast                       0.00231 *
my.disease                        0.07690 .
my.profile:my.contrast            0.26159  
my.profile:my.disease             0.07709 .
my.contrast:my.disease            0.21256  
my.profile:my.contrast:my.disease 0.23319
```

**Use the rule of marginality:**

*update no. 1:*
you can see that triple interaction is non-significant - let's remove it

```
m2 <- update(m1, ~.-my.profile:my.contrast:my.disease)
```

Now, show the anova of updated model:

```
anova(m2, test = "F")

my.profile                        0.00012 **
my.contrast                       0.00231 *
my.disease                        0.07690 .
my.profile:my.contrast            0.26159  
my.profile:my.disease             0.07709 .
my.contrast:my.disease            0.21256
```

*update no. 2:*
you can see that double interactions are non-significant - let's remove them  (start with double interaction with highest p-value)

```
m3 <- update(m2, ~.-my.profile:my.contrast)

anova(m3, test = "F")

my.profile                        0.00012 **
my.contrast                       0.00231 *
my.disease                        0.07690 .
my.profile:my.disease             0.07709 .
my.contrast:my.disease            0.21256
```

*update no. 3:*
remove another double interaction

```
m4 <- update(m3, ~.-my.contrast:my.disease)

anova(m4, test = "F")

my.profile                        0.00012 **
my.contrast                       0.00231 *
my.disease                        0.07690 .
my.profile:my.disease             0.07709 .
```

*update no. 4:*
remove the last double interaction

```
m5 <- update(m4, ~.-my.profile:my.disease)

anova(m5, test = "F")

my.profile                        0.00012 **
my.contrast                       0.00231 *
my.disease                        0.07690 .
```

*update no. 5:*
remove non-significant factor

```
m6 <- update(m5, ~.-my.disease)

anova(m6, test = "F")

my.profile                        0.00012 **
my.contrast                       0.00231 *
```

**Model m6 is our final model.**

Unfortunately it is obvious that **making comparisons
(Y.NEG.NO, X.NEG.NO and others) has no sense, because the triple and double interaction are non-significant as well**. And it would not be correct
to select the desired rows from TukeyHSD (even if such post-hoc will show significant difference !!!).
Believe me, such approach will be very hard to defend in peer-review process.
So you can make only comparison in profile (X vs. Y) and contrast (NO vs. YES).
Disease factor is non-significant.
Do not be sad - even non-significant result is a result.

**[Marginality rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_marginality) is the practical application of [Occam's razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor)** (See also in Crawley, M.J. Statistics: An Introduction Using R. 2nd ed. Wiley, 2014, Ch. 10 Multiple Regression, p. 195). A good model is always the simplest one - and explains the largest portion of variability in data.

You can publish this result in an article as a **"full model"**
(containing all the factors and their interaction(s)) or as a **"minimal
adequate model"** (MAM, containing only significant effects). I would prefer to include both versions into a manuscript and let reviewers to decide which one to prefer.

The point is not to fishing for p-values in post-hoc tests when ANOVA results are non-significant.

Comment: Great, this is has really helped set me on the right course.  But for multiple factors, do I need multiple matrices, a higher dimensional array, or can it be done with one matrix the way you describe?

Comment: smallData <- data.frame(measurement = c(rnorm(5),rnorm(7),rnorm(23-(5+7))), profile = c(rep("X",7),rep("Y",23-7)), contrast = c(rep("YES",10),rep("NO",23-10)),disease = c(rep("POS",14),rep("NEG",23-14)))

Comment: I'm looking to model measurement ~ profile + contrast + disease but I'm only interested in the comparisons listed above.

Comment: There are 82 rows overall.

Comment: I've added some example code to reproduce the format of my data.  Thanks!

Comment: Fixed the typo ... now it makes more sense.

Comment: Note that I've extended this procedure above down to only 3 variables.

Answer (score 0):

Running `step` on your model will also work.

```
# Full model
m1.0 = glm (logICPMS ~ SITE*ISLAND*ORG*ORGL*CAGE*Metal,
            data = M.m, na.action = na.exclude)

# this removes each interacting factor to give you the MAM model
step(m1.0)

# MAM model
m1.1 = glm(formula = logICPMS ~ ISLAND + ORG + CAGE + Metal + ISLAND:ORG + 
                                ISLAND:CAGE + ISLAND:Metal + ORG:Metal, 
           data = M.m, na.action = na.exclude)
```

Comment: Stepwise selection methods are generally considered a bad idea (see [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20856/7290)).

Comment: Since making *post hoc* comparisons is not the usual purpose of stepwise regression, could you please explain *how* and *why* this recommendation answers the question?