# T-test and ANOVA suggesting different results?

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, t-test, interaction, interpretation

I'd like to start off by saying I am very much a beginner to statistical analyses, so I might be missing some key ideas here.

Context: My study involves an experimental group and control group that received different exercises. Within the groups, some participants identified as male, some as female. I measured participant satisfaction in completing the exercises.

Question: I want to know if the experiences of female students within the two groups differed in terms of how satisfied they were.

Tests run: 
(1) A two-way ANOVA with female/male + group (experimental or control) as my two independent variables, and satisfaction measure (based on survey of scale questions) as dependent variable. 
(2) I conducted t-test of just female students and compared their motivation ratings in experimental vs. control group, and another t-test of just male students and compared their satisfaction ratings in experimental vs. control group.

Results:
(1) The ANOVA showed non-significant effects (p > 0.05) for both gender, and gender * group interaction.
(2) The t-tests showed that female students had significantly higher satisfaction in experimental group, and male students had no difference in satisfaction among the two groups.

Question:
Doesn't the results of (2) suggest an interaction effect? Unless I'm misunderstanding what ANOVA results mean completely.. I checked all assumptions of normality and equality of variances before running each of the tests using SPSS.

Comment: How many participants were in each group for your IVs? Also, what were the p-values when you ran the ANOVA?

Comment: Yes, please give us the ANOVA and t-test results. It seems that the group effect was significant? But that was mainly driven by females?

Answer (score 0):

A better way to approach this analysis could be to:

1. Fit the ANOVA model to test the [overall significance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omnibus_test) and/or;
2. Perform pairwise comparisons on the ANOVA model to test individual effects for significance while controlling the [Family Wise Error Rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family-wise_error_rate) (FWER), *e.g.* [Tukey's HSD test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tukey%27s_range_test), [Dunnett's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunnett%27s_test). Your t-test results apparently were not adjusted for multiple comparisons?

You might also find the following posts helpful:

- [Anova vs Summary in the analysis of models and variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/204940/anova-vs-summary-in-the-analysis-of-models-and-variables)
- [Interpreting output from anova() when using lm() as input](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115304/interpreting-output-from-anova-when-using-lm-as-input)
- [Relation between omnibus test and multiple comparison?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59910/relation-between-omnibus-test-and-multiple-comparison)
- [How to get only desirable comparisons from post-hoc](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89021/how-to-get-only-desirable-comparisons-from-post-hoc/89035#89035)

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem here is interpreting the main effect when there's a significant interaction. This is generally bad practice.

A secondary issue is comparing an ANOVA with a t-test on a much smaller sample size. The degrees of freedom in the models are very different.

Using the output of the ANOVA makes most sense here.